# How to recompile .java back to .dex

Tags: java, compilation, reverse-engineering, dex

I have decompiled **.dex** to **.java** using **JADX** . Now how do I compile back the whole program into **.dex** file?

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar

This project has **dex2jar** and **jar2dex** apps/scripts.

Also you should probably take a look at https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ as a way to decompile and re-compile Android apps.